# Android, sharedpreferences in Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, android-arrayadapter

What is the best way to use sharedpreferences in list adapter getview methods?
I have to use some values from sharedpreferences but have no idea how to get it. 
I tried:

```
pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

it works in activity
and:

```
SharedPreferences pref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

works in fragment but both don't work in listadapter.

Comment: What do you see when used in an `Adapter`?  What `Context` are you using?

Comment: The solution is to first use getContext()

Answer (score 10):

You can pass the `Context` as a field in the constructor of your `ListAdapter` and use the `context` field to get the `SharedPreferences`.